# SimpleXml conditional

Tags: php, simplexml

Hi I need to filter the xml that was given to me base on the following conditions
ex. 
category needs to be Transportation, 
package needs to be Good 
and the last one item needs to have been publish today only.

here is the sample xml

```
<item>
    <category>Transportaion</category>
    <package>Good</package>
    <date>2018-04-17 17:10:46</date>
    <title>Item sample 1</title>
    <description>This is a sample</description>
</item>
<item>
    <category>Wanted</category>
    <package>Good</package>
    <date>2018-04-17 18:03:46</date>
    <title>Item sample 2</title>
    <description>This is a sample</description>
</item>
<item>
    <category>For sale</category>
    <package>Better</package>
    <date>2018-04-16 14:03:46</date>
    <title>Item sample 3</title>
    <description>This is a sample</description>
</item>
```

I was able to do the 1st two conditions but I'm clueless about the the last condition Include items published today

here is the code I used

```
$data= simplexml_load_file("easy2.xml");
$today= date('Y-m-d');
foreach ($data->item as $item)
{
    if ($item->category == 'Transportaion' && $item->package == 'Good' && $item->date == '$today')
    {
        echo "Title: " . $item->title . "<br>";
        echo "Category: " . $item->category . "<br>";
    }
}
```

can someone please advice, many thanks

Comment: In your xml the date will never be written litteraly as 'today'. You must use date function http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to convert item->date and then compare it to date of today

Comment: I just added 'today' as a place holder since I am not sure what to do. I was able to check the link you gave me before but I am not sure how to convert  item->date and compare

Comment: I made some changes and I was able to make it work using a a var with today's date do you think this is advisable? Thanks

Comment: If you know the item date format is always the same format, you can rely on it. Otherwise it won't work if the date is `16/04/2018` instead of `2018-04-16 14:03:46` for example

Comment: Thanks Med, yes I saw another date field with that format y-m-d without the time so that would make it easier for me