# Conditional inside echo in simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

I am using simplexml to get the data from an xml I have 3 conditions the category must be jazz the package must be best and the date must be today. That one is sorted out my problem is echoing the title since field that has the ad title moves depending on the ad.

here is a sample of the xml

```
    <product>
    <export>
        <ad>
        <category>
            <name>Jazz</name>
        </category>
        <package>
            <name>Good</name>
            <start_date>2018-04-18</start_date>
            <adcopy>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec consequat ante. Aenean suscipit imperdiet velit, sed congue felis congue vel. Maecenas non leo at tortor ornare iaculis.</adcopy>
        </package>
        </ad>
        <fields>
          <field>
            <name>Color</name>
            <value>white/blue</value>
          </field>
          <field>
            <name>AdTitle</name>
            <value>This is the Title of my 1st item</value>
          </field>
          <field>
            <name>Make</name>
            <value>Plastic</value>
          </field>
        </fields>
    </export>
    <export>
        <ad>
        <category>
            <name>RNB</name>
        </category>
        <package>
            <name>Good</name>
            <start_date>2018-04-17</start_date>
            <adcopy>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nec consequat ante. Aenean suscipit imperdiet velit, sed congue felis congue vel. Maecenas non leo at tortor ornare iaculis.</adcopy>
        </package>
        </ad>
        <fields>
          <field>
            <name>AdTitle</name>
            <value>This is the Title of my 2nd item</value>
          </field>
          <field>
            <name>Color</name>
            <value>white/blue</value>
          </field>
          <field>
            <name>Make</name>
            <value>Plastic</value>
          </field>
        </fields>
    </export>
</product>
```

And here is the script

```
    foreach ($data->export as $item)
{
    if ($item->ad->category->name == 'Jazz' && $item->ad->package->name == 'Good' && $item->ad->package->start_date == $currentday)
    {
        echo "Title: " . $item->fields->field->value . "<br>";
        echo "Description: " . $item->ad->package->adcopy->value . "<br>";
        echo "Date: " . $item->ad->package->start_date . "<br>";

    }
}
```

How can I do this?
if the field has a name of AdTitle, use that field and show the field->value (which is the title of the ad)

Please help

I tried adding below but it's not working

```
echo "Issue" . (($item->fields->field->name == 'AdTitle') ? $item->fields->field->value :'')."<br>";
```

I  was able to make it work with below

```
{
            foreach ($item->fields->field as $field)
                {
                    if ($field->name == 'AdTitle')
                        {
                            echo "Title: " . $field->value . "<br>";
```

Comment: any advice on this would be much appreciated thanks

Comment: This question is weirdly similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49900752/simplexml-conditional Are you both doing the same homework assignment or something?

Comment: Meanwhile, you need to be more specific that "it's not working" - does it give you too little output? too much? an error message? And how does the "not working" line relate to the `foreach` loop in your other code block? Please [edit] the question to explain exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Saw that too much of the code I am using was from other forums on web might be the same one he is using. The code does not show any error it's just empty.

Comment: I was able to make it work thanks

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. The convention here is to keep Questions and Answers separate, so [you can answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer); that way, it's clear to future readers that the problem is solved.